# Excel Data cross referencing

Tags: excel, merge

I have data  on two separate sheets

One sheet has Rows LA, HS, HC, AS, AC

and second data set has  LA, ALC, ALS

I want to use excel to merge the data with the common data link "LA"

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question doesn't meet the guidelines for posting to this site. I recommend that you find a site with the word "forum" in the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *hlookup* (assuming that your data is in rows) to look up data from the second sheet into the first sheet. The syntax is hlookup(what to look for, where to look for it, what to return, FALSE). For example, hlookup(LA1, sheet2!$LA$1:$ALS$100, 2, false) will look up the value in LA1 and when it finds it in sheet2!$LA$1:$ALS$100, it returns the second row of the specified range (ALC in this case) and returns it. If it cannot find the value N/A error will be reported.